# PHP code in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to have my code add this 2 fields to a form (quantities and products) on a click of a button.

How do I format my script so the innerHTML can include php code?
Or is there another way to add a select element via JS?

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='quantities[]'> <select name='products[]'>
                        <?php
                            $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM inventory");
                            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                                echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>";
```

Comment: Escape the JavaScript string. PHP runs separately (first) before any JavaScript is ran.

Answer (score 3):

PHP code is interpreted *by your server* before the page is even sent to the browser. The server then sends a completed html page (no PHP code) across the internet to your browser, which then loads it and **then** executes the JavaScript *in the browser*.  The PHP interpreter would have no way of reading what the JavaScript changes on the finished page.

You might want to look into [making an Ajax call to a PHP page](http://thisinterestsme.com/simple-ajax-request-example-jquery-php/), your PHP page can then contain the sql query and return data the JavaScript can use to add the options.